# Plugin gradle in android studio don't work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins, api-key

I want use gradle plugin in android studio.
I added classpath in build.gralde:

```
 classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
```

and

```
 id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
```

I put my map api key in local.properties (MAPS_API_KEY = "mykey") and use it on my manifest:

```
 <meta-data           
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

My app run succefully But it's don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you mention it, but when you specify a variable such as ${MAPS_API_KEY}, a value has to be provided that will be substituted later.

For your case, Google recommends using the "local.properties" file.  Add an entry there of:

MAPS_API_KEY = ***your key value***

So that the ${MAPS_API_KEY} can be populated with your actual key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I put my map api key in local.properties and use it on my manifest but don't show google map.